# What is the best way to handle dev, test and prod enviroment in jenkins?

Tags: java, jenkins, hudson

I have started to implement Jenkins where in my job, I have just few weeks on it !.

I started to understand how it works, but ah this time I have the question that it is:

How I will handle 3 enviroments with Jenkins? What is the best way to keep developers, test and production enviroment?

Will I need to keep 3 jenkins per enviroment?
It is the best way 1 Jenkins instance to handle all enviroments?

This is just the first approach to continous Integration and DevOps !

I will appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Use single jenkins Master to handle all these 3 environment.
connect your dev,test,production systems as your jenkins slave node.

Comment: Thank you , CI needs to read a lot !, actually that is what I learning !